# Is Erlang a good choice for a booking system backend?

Tags: erlang, backend

I need to write the backend for an event ticket selling system. Some companies would connect to the service in order to check for ticket availability in certain venues, book tickets and so on.

Reading about Erlang I though it could be a good choice since the system will have to support high concurrency, high availability but I don't know If it's a good choice for this problem domain.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Erlang could be a good choice, yes, it sounds like something it would do a very good job.

But it's going to be hard for anyone here to be of much value for your decision, as you should also consider the knowledge level of the team, time & budget constraints, etc.

Ultimately, the best people to help you make this decision are the people in your team.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at [OTP's finite state machines](http://erldocs.com/17.0-rc1/stdlib/gen_fsm.html) as I think it suits perfectly a ticket booking system.

I believe you can find a lot of examples either in the doc or on the web.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I read about FSM and Client-Server design patterns in Erlang. According to the docs Client-Server is more appropiate for resource management problems such as the problem I exposed. Would you model every ticket and its possible states as a FSM? Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Very quickly (LYSE)](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/finite-state-machines#a-trading-system-specification), see your booking algorithm as a sequence of actions one following the other; eg. as sequence diagram.